# swipe controls in my script not working as intended in c# unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, swipe

**This code works for like 2min and stops taking swipe input, i need to relaunch the editor then again it works for 2min. if i did same with keyboard input it works just fine. there is a problem in swipemanager ill put both code................................................................................................................................................................................................**

```
using UnityEngine;

public class SwipeManager : MonoBehaviour
{
public static bool tap, swipeLeft, swipeRight, swipeUp, swipeDown;
private bool isDraging = false;
private Vector2 startTouch, swipeDelta;

private void Update()
{
    tap = swipeDown = swipeUp = swipeLeft = swipeRight = false;
    #region Standalone Inputs
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        tap = true;
        isDraging = true;
        startTouch = Input.mousePosition;
    }
    else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    {
        isDraging = false;
        Reset();
    }
    #endregion

    #region Mobile Input
    if (Input.touches.Length > 0)
    {
        if (Input.touches[0].phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            tap = true;
            isDraging = true;
            startTouch = Input.touches[0].position;
        }
        else if (Input.touches[0].phase == TouchPhase.Ended || Input.touches[0].phase == TouchPhase.Canceled)
        {
            isDraging = false;
            Reset();
        }
    }
    #endregion

    //Calculate the distance
    swipeDelta = Vector2.zero;
    if (isDraging)
    {
        if (Input.touches.Length < 0)
            swipeDelta = Input.touches[0].position - startTouch;
        else if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
            swipeDelta = (Vector2)Input.mousePosition - startTouch;
    }

    //Did we cross the distance?
    if (swipeDelta.magnitude > 100)
    {
        //Which direction?
        float x = swipeDelta.x;
        float y = swipeDelta.y;
        if (Mathf.Abs(x) > Mathf.Abs(y))
        {
            //Left or Right
            if (x < 0)
                swipeLeft = true;
            else
                swipeRight = true;
        }
        else
        {
            //Up or Down
            if (y < 0)
                swipeDown = true;
            else
                swipeUp = true;
        }

        Reset();
    }

}

private void Reset()
{
    startTouch = swipeDelta = Vector2.zero;
    isDraging = false;
}}
```

**This is code of playermanager**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
public static bool tap, swipeLeft, swipeRight, swipeUp, swipeDown;
private bool isDraging = false;
private Vector2 startTouch, swipeDelta;

// Start is called before the first frame update
private CharacterController controller;
private Vector3 direction;
public float forwardSpeed;
private int desiredLane = 1;//1=left 2=middle 3=right
public float laneDistance;
public float Jumpforce;
public float Gravity = -20;
public GameObject GameOver;
public float MaxSpeed;
public  Animator animator;
public SwipeManager sm;

void Start()
{
    controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if(!PlayerManager.isGameStarted)
        return;
    
    animator.SetBool("isGameStarted", true);
    if(forwardSpeed<MaxSpeed)
        forwardSpeed += 0.05f* Time.deltaTime;

    direction.z = forwardSpeed;
    animator.SetBool("IsGrounded", controller.isGrounded);
    if (controller.isGrounded)
    {
        direction.y = -1;
        if (SwipeManager.swipeUp)
        {
            Jump();  
        }
    }
    else { direction.y += Gravity * Time.deltaTime; }

    if (SwipeManager.swipeDown)
    {
        StartCoroutine(slide());
    }
    if (SwipeManager.swipeRight)
    {
        desiredLane++;
        if (desiredLane == 3)
            desiredLane = 2;
    }

    if (SwipeManager.swipeLeft)
    {
        desiredLane--;
        if (desiredLane == -1)
            desiredLane = 0;
    }
    Vector3 targetPosition = transform.position.z * transform.forward + transform.position.y * transform.up;

    if (desiredLane == 0)
    {
        targetPosition += Vector3.left * laneDistance;
    }
    else if (desiredLane == 2)
    {
        targetPosition += Vector3.right * laneDistance;
    }
    transform.position = targetPosition;
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    if(!PlayerManager.isGameStarted)
        return;
    controller.Move(direction * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
}
public void Jump()
{
    direction.y = Jumpforce;
}
private void OnControllerColliderHit(ControllerColliderHit hit)
{
    if (hit.transform.tag == "Obstacle")
    {
        GameOver.SetActive(true);
        Time.timeScale = 0;
    }
}

private IEnumerator slide()
{
    controller.center = new Vector3(0,-0.5f,0);
    controller.height = 1;
    animator.SetBool("isCrouching", true);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.3f);

    controller.center = new Vector3(0,0,0);
    animator.SetBool("isCrouching", false);
    controller.height = 2;
}}
```

Comment: are you sure that `swipeDelta = Vector2.zero;` belongs in update getting zero every frame?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `swipeDelta = Vector2.zero;` should be called in the `Start()` function and your `Reset()` function only, as in the `Update()` it is getting zero every frame.

Comment: Thank you i found a fix its not in swipe manager its in the playercontroller i messed up with jump